# git pull Deleted My Files with Remote

Tags: git, github

We are 2 people working on the same project. My friend told me that he has done his part and pushed it to GitHub. My part has finished today so I wanted to push too.

To accomplish, I wanted to pull first, merge the files locally and then push it back again.

While I was trying to update my local repo with his commit, I used `git pull`, this resulted with all my work gone, and instead of my files, his files appeared.

I want to recover my files and then correctly update my repo with his files.

It is good mentioning the process: I got a local branch named "entrance" so first, I switched to master, then `git merge entrance` for the files being merged, which showed something on screen so I thought merge is done. So at last, I used `git pull`.

Comment: Did you have your changes committed?

Comment: Ah yeah, forgot to mention @MadaraUchiha . I didn't committed after that issue came up

Comment: I bet your stuff is gone because you switched branches. If you do `git checkout entrance` is your stuff back?

Comment: Just wanted to people feel relax. Thanks @TimCastelijns

Comment: If not, `git reflog` will show you a history of the state of your repo, and you can find your work and check it out there

Comment: I did checkout to entrance again, nothing happens. Lets see what reflog will give, I will back in a min @AaronBrager

Comment: well as you all suggested, I peeked and tried reverse but now it also gone too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i meet that case, I will do the steps below:

1. At the first, make sure that you commit your code before pulling your friend's code.
2. Show `reflog` to check the history by command: `git reflog` The output should be:

> ```
> $ git reflog
> 90abbe3 HEAD@{0}: pull origin master: Fast-forward
> 3ab3527 HEAD@{1}: commit: q defer all
> 962e856 HEAD@{2}: commit: getall terms by tax
> 2d7f20d HEAD@{3}: commit: bug list create
> ```

2. Reset to the previous commit by command: `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`
3. Investigating the reason why my code gone by using some commands `git diff`, `git branch` ..
4. Finally, find the issue and merge the source agian by `git merge` or `git pull`

Comment: Thank you Ngyuyen hahahaha. You save my entire work